# Structr ui mvn validation

Tags: maven, structr

I tried to install Strctr according to the instructions on [github](https://github.com/structr/structr) page. In the last step of quick start guide when I run

```
mvn validate exec:exec
```

I get the following errors after some downloads/installations on my Terminal, and structr does not run on my localhost:8082/structr

```
INFO: AgentService started
Jun 19, 2015 11:12:51 AM org.structr.cron.CronService initialize
WARNING: No cron expression for task , ignoring.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class      org.structr.schema.compiler.NodeExtender
at org.structr.schema.SchemaService.reloadSchema(SchemaService.java:86)
at org.structr.schema.SchemaService.initialize(SchemaService.java:65)
at org.structr.core.Services.createService(Services.java:537)
at org.structr.core.Services.initialize(Services.java:305)
at org.structr.core.Services.initialize(Services.java:271)
at org.structr.core.Services.getInstance(Services.java:142)
at org.structr.Server.main(Server.java:36)
Jun 19, 2015 11:12:51 AM org.structr.core.Services createService
SEVERE: Vital service SchemaService failed to start: Could not    initialize class org.structr.schema.compiler.NodeExtender. Aborting
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.253s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 19 12:12:51 EEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/214M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-   plugin:1.4.0:exec (default-cli) on project structr-ui: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with    the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I am not familiar with coding/programming so much. Does anyone have any idea/suggestion about the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure: Do you have the JDK 1.7 (or 1.8) installed or just the JRE?
The error sounds like that might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes JDK 1.7 is installed. I am using Ubuntu version 15. I tried the installation in another computer which has same configurations and worked. It worked in Windows 7 platform as well. I am not quite sure but the default language of my pc is not English. May it be the reason, because sometimes I get errors due to this reason for some other installations/configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to verify for Java Version JDK 1.7 or latest and also install maven.